# Anyone been able to install DBD::mysql on Mac Snow Leopard with i5 Processor?

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi, dbd

I'm trying to install DBD::mysql using most of the popular methods, including `sudo cpanm -S DBD::mysql`. However, I am having some serious problems with this and I am beginning to think it might be my processor. I have successfully installed this on many computers, but every since my IT department gave me this i5 MacBook Pro, no luck. Has anyone else been able to install DBD::mysql on an i5? I'm running Mac OS 10.6.8.

Here is build.log after running `cpanm`. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.4008 on perl 5.010000 built for darwin-thread-multi-2level
Work directory is /Users/jerickson/.cpanm/work/1314049977.98062
You have make /usr/bin/make
You have LWP 5.813
You have /usr/bin/tar: bsdtar 2.6.2 - libarchive 2.6.2
You have /usr/bin/unzip
Searching DBD::mysql on cpanmetadb ...
--> Working on DBD::mysql
Fetching http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/C/CA/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.020.tar.gz
-> OK
Unpacking DBD-mysql-4.020.tar.gz
Entering DBD-mysql-4.020
Checking configure dependencies from META.yml
Checking if you have DBI 1.08 ... Yes (1.616)
Configuring DBD-mysql-4.020
Running Makefile.PL


PLEASE NOTE:

For 'make test' to run properly, you must ensure that the 
database user 'root' can connect to your MySQL server 
and has the proper privileges that these tests require such 
as 'drop table', 'create table', 'drop procedure', 'create procedure'
as well as others. 

mysql> grant all privileges on test.* to 'root'@'localhost' identified by 's3kr1t';

You can also optionally set the user to run 'make test' with:

perl Makefile.PL --testuser=username

I will use the following settings for compiling and testing:

  cflags        (mysql_config) = -I/usr/local/mysql/include  -Os -g -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -arch x86_64
  embedded      (mysql_config) = 
  libs          (mysql_config) = -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -lmysqlclient   -lpthread
  mysql_config  (guessed     ) = mysql_config
  nocatchstderr (default     ) = 0
  nofoundrows   (default     ) = 0
  ssl           (guessed     ) = 0
  testdb        (default     ) = test
  testhost      (default     ) = 
  testpassword  (default     ) = 
  testsocket    (default     ) = 
  testuser      (guessed     ) = root

To change these settings, see 'perl Makefile.PL --help' and
'perldoc INSTALL'.

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Using DBI 1.616 (for perl 5.010000 on darwin-thread-multi-2level) installed in /Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBI/
Writing Makefile for DBD::mysql
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
-> OK
Checking dependencies from MYMETA.yml ...
Finding PREREQ from Makefile ...
Checking if you have Data::Dumper 0 ... Yes (2.121_14)
Checking if you have DBI 1.08 ... Yes (1.616)
Checking if you have Test::More 0 ... Yes (0.98)
Checking if you have Test::More 0 ... Yes (0.98)
Checking if you have Data::Dumper 0 ... Yes (2.121_14)
Checking if you have DBI 1.08 ... Yes (1.616)
Building and testing DBD-mysql-4.020
cp lib/DBD/mysql.pm blib/lib/DBD/mysql.pm
cp lib/DBD/mysql/GetInfo.pm blib/lib/DBD/mysql/GetInfo.pm
cp lib/DBD/mysql/INSTALL.pod blib/lib/DBD/mysql/INSTALL.pod
cp lib/Bundle/DBD/mysql.pm blib/lib/Bundle/DBD/mysql.pm
gcc-4.2 -c  -I/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBI -I/usr/local/mysql/include  -Os -g -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -arch x86_64 -DDBD_MYSQL_INSERT_ID_IS_GOOD -g  -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -arch ppc -g -pipe -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -I/usr/local/include -Os   -DVERSION=\"4.020\" -DXS_VERSION=\"4.020\"  "-I/System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"   dbdimp.c
dbdimp.c: In function ‘alloc_param’:
dbdimp.c:223: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
dbdimp.c: In function ‘alloc_bind’:
dbdimp.c:241: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
dbdimp.c: In function ‘alloc_fbind’:
dbdimp.c:257: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
dbdimp.c: In function ‘alloc_fbuffer’:
dbdimp.c:272: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
dbdimp.c: In function ‘parse_params’:
dbdimp.c:589: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
dbdimp.c: In function ‘my_login’:
dbdimp.c:1996: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
dbdimp.c: In function ‘mysql_describe’:
dbdimp.c:3605: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
dbdimp.c:3606: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
dbdimp.c: In function ‘mysql_st_fetch’:
dbdimp.c:3798: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
dbdimp.c: In function ‘alloc_param’:
dbdimp.c:223: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
dbdimp.c: In function ‘alloc_bind’:
dbdimp.c:241: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
dbdimp.c: In function ‘alloc_fbind’:
dbdimp.c:257: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
dbdimp.c: In function ‘alloc_fbuffer’:
dbdimp.c:272: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
dbdimp.c: In function ‘parse_params’:
dbdimp.c:589: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
dbdimp.c: In function ‘my_login’:
dbdimp.c:1996: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
dbdimp.c: In function ‘mysql_describe’:
dbdimp.c:3605: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
dbdimp.c:3606: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
dbdimp.c: In function ‘mysql_st_fetch’:
dbdimp.c:3798: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
dbdimp.c: In function ‘alloc_param’:
dbdimp.c:223: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
dbdimp.c: In function ‘alloc_bind’:
dbdimp.c:241: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
dbdimp.c: In function ‘alloc_fbind’:
dbdimp.c:257: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
dbdimp.c: In function ‘alloc_fbuffer’:
dbdimp.c:272: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
dbdimp.c: In function ‘parse_params’:
dbdimp.c:589: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
dbdimp.c: In function ‘my_login’:
dbdimp.c:1996: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
dbdimp.c: In function ‘mysql_describe’:
dbdimp.c:3605: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
dbdimp.c:3606: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
dbdimp.c: In function ‘mysql_st_fetch’:
dbdimp.c:3798: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
/usr/bin/perl -p -e "s/~DRIVER~/mysql/g" /Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBI/Driver.xst > mysql.xsi
/usr/bin/perl /Library/Perl/Updates/5.10.0/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/ExtUtils/typemap  mysql.xs > mysql.xsc && mv mysql.xsc mysql.c
Warning: duplicate function definition 'do' detected in mysql.xs, line 242
Warning: duplicate function definition 'rows' detected in mysql.xs, line 751
gcc-4.2 -c  -I/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBI -I/usr/local/mysql/include  -Os -g -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -arch x86_64 -DDBD_MYSQL_INSERT_ID_IS_GOOD -g  -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -arch ppc -g -pipe -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -I/usr/local/include -Os   -DVERSION=\"4.020\" -DXS_VERSION=\"4.020\"  "-I/System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"   mysql.c
mysql.xs: In function ‘XS_DBD__mysql__db_do’:
mysql.xs:307: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘struct SV *’
mysql.xs:364: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
mysql.xs:365: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
mysql.xs:366: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
mysql.xs:525: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
mysql.xs: In function ‘XS_DBD__mysql__GetInfo_dbd_mysql_get_info’:
mysql.xs:930: warning: format ‘%i’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘struct SV *’
mysql.xs: In function ‘XS_DBD__mysql__db_do’:
mysql.xs:307: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘struct SV *’
mysql.xs:364: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
mysql.xs:365: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
mysql.xs:366: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
mysql.xs:525: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
mysql.xs: In function ‘XS_DBD__mysql__GetInfo_dbd_mysql_get_info’:
mysql.xs:930: warning: format ‘%i’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘struct SV *’
mysql.xs: In function ‘XS_DBD__mysql__db_do’:
mysql.xs:307: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘struct SV *’
mysql.xs:364: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
mysql.xs:365: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
mysql.xs:366: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
mysql.xs:525: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
mysql.xs: In function ‘XS_DBD__mysql__GetInfo_dbd_mysql_get_info’:
mysql.xs:930: warning: format ‘%i’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘struct SV *’
Running Mkbootstrap for DBD::mysql ()
chmod 644 mysql.bs
rm -f blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle
LD_RUN_PATH="/usr/local/mysql/lib:/usr/lib" /usr/bin/perl myld gcc-4.2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.6.3  -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -arch ppc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/lib dbdimp.o mysql.o  -o blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle     \
       -L/usr/local/mysql/lib -lmysqlclient -lpthread   \

chmod 755 blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle
cp mysql.bs blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bs
chmod 644 blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bs
Manifying blib/man3/DBD::mysql.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBD::mysql::INSTALL.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/Bundle::DBD::mysql.3pm
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
Bailout called.  Further testing stopped:  Unable to load DBD::mysql

#   Failed test 'use DBD::mysql;'
#   at t/00base.t line 21.
#     Tried to use 'DBD::mysql'.
#     Error:  Can't load '/Users/jerickson/.cpanm/work/1314049977.98062/DBD-mysql-4.020/blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle' for module DBD::mysql: dlopen(/Users/jerickson/.cpanm/work/1314049977.98062/DBD-mysql-4.020/blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
#   Referenced from: /Users/jerickson/.cpanm/work/1314049977.98062/DBD-mysql-4.020/blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle
#   Reason: image not found at /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DynaLoader.pm line 207.
#  at (eval 7) line 2
# Compilation failed in require at (eval 7) line 2.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 7) line 2.
FAILED--Further testing stopped: Unable to load DBD::mysql
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
-> FAIL Installing DBD::mysql failed. See /Users/jerickson/.cpanm/build.log for details.
```

I have since tried `sudo cpanm -Sf DBD::mysql`. Using the force flag, cpanm says that it was installed successfully, however trying to run a script that includes connecting to a MySQL database results with this error:

```
Running...
install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't load '/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle' for module DBD::mysql: dlopen(/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle, 1): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle
  Reason: image not found at /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DynaLoader.pm line 207.
 at (eval 6) line 3
Compilation failed in require at (eval 6) line 3.
Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where expected
 at roster_generate.pl line 33
```

Comment: FWIW, I've hit the same generally issue and force installed DBD::mysql on every OS X since the Public Beta and it's worked fine afterward. I realize this isn't "correct" advice but it hasn't caused me any grief in 10 years of doing it over and over.

Comment: @Ashley I tried to force install it with the -Sf flag and it says that it was installed successfully, however I am still not able to use it in a Perl script. Please see modified post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, I was able to fix it by adding

`export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/mysql/lib/"`

to my .bash_profile. I found this on some random blog. Anyone know why this worked??

Comment: Here is the source: http://www.blog.bridgeutopiaweb.com/post/how-to-fix-mysql-load-issues-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped me complete my Mysql <-> DBD installation !

Comment: The correct link is now http://c.kat.pe/post/how-to-fix-mysql-load-issues-on-mac-os-x/

Answer (score 2):

I got the following to work on Snow Leopard.  It's an old linux trick from the Dark Ages called symlinks.

cd /usr/lib
sudo ln -sv /usr/local/mysql/lib/*.dylib .

Don't mess with setting the environment variable DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH because sudo will not respect and give you a pissy message to boot.

I was able to (finally) compile DBD::mysql and a few other things.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using Mac OSX Mavericks, here are the steps I used to finally get this module working.

First, uninstall DBD::mysql if it is already installed.

```
sudo cpanm -U DBD::mysql
```

Run the following commands to link the MySQL lib files.  As jjohn mentioned, setting the variable DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH will not work.

```
cd /usr/lib
sudo ln -sv /usr/local/mysql/lib/*.dylib .
```

Re-install DBD::mysql (the -n flag skips the testing phase).

```
sudo cpanm -n DBD::mysql
```

That's it!

For good measure, I also configured Perl to run in 32-bit mode, and I restarted Apache.  However, I am not sure if these steps are required.  Here are the commands to do this, respectively:

```
defaults write com.apple.versioner.perl Prefer-32-Bit -bool yes
sudo apachectl restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried to install the DBD::mysql package myself on a entirely different machine with the same error. The installer needs certain libraries from the mysql-devel package, unfortunately it doesn't tell you this. After installing this mysql-devel package with yum the installation went without any problem.

I guess by setting the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable the installer looks in `/usr/local/mysql/lib/` too in order to find the required libraries.